# Как составить select запрос чтобы найти общие теги фильмов и сериалов?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

У меня есть 3 таблицы: Фильмы, Теги, Теги_Записи

```
create table movies (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    title varchar(255),
    type int unsigned not null default 1,
    primary key(id)
);
```

В таблице movies, поле type может иметь значения 0 для сериалов и 1 для фильмов.

```
create table tags (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key(id)
);
```

```
create table tags_items (
    tag_id int unsigned not null,
    movie_id int unsigned not null
);
```

Подробнее: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5e3d2/6

Когда я хочу узнать, сколько тегов у меня к фильмам или сериалам я делаю запрос:

```
select ti.* from tags_items ti
  join movies m on m.id = ti.movie_id
    where m.type = 1
      group by tag_id
```

Как мне можно сделать запрос, чтобы найти общие теги и для фильмов и для сериалов? Мои попытки сравнивать таблицу tags_items с самой собой не привели к успеху.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно выбрать `tags` где айдишники равны айдишникам из `tags_items` которые в свою очередь содержаться в фильмах и сериалах

Не совсем аккуратно но отображает описанное выше

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM tags_items ti, tags t
    where t.id in(SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM tags_items
          where tag_id in (
            SELECT ti.tag_id FROM tags_items ti, movies m
            where ti.movie_id = m.id and m.type = 1
          )
          and tag_id in (
            SELECT ti.tag_id FROM tags_items ti, movies m
            where ti.movie_id = m.id and m.type = 0
          )
     );
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e99c5/1/0)

Comment: Tiarait, спасибо за ответ. На тестовой выборке работает, но если таблица tags_items содержит около миллиона записей, то запрос не завершается.